# How to get a list with the Typesafe config library

Tags: scala, typesafe

I'm trying in Scala to get a list from a config file like `something.conf` with `TypeSafe`.

In `something.conf` I set the parameter:

```
mylist=["AA","BB"]
```

and in my Scala code I do:

```
val myList = modifyConfig.getStringList("mylist")
```

Simple configuration parameters works fine but could somebody give me an example of how to extract a list?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Looking at the API, your code looks fine. You should find a `List[String]` in `myList`.

Comment: My guess is that you expect the result of `getStringList` to be a Scala `List`. This is not the case - `typesafe-config` is a pure Java library and `getStringList` returns an implementation of `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As @ghik notes, the Typesafe Config library is *Java* based, so you get a `java.util.List[String]` instead of a `scala.List[String]`. So either you make a conversion to a `scala.List`:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
val myList = modifyConfig.getStringList("mylist").toList
```

Or (probably less awkward) you look for a Scala library. The [tools wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries) links at least to these maintained libraries:

- [Configrity](https://github.com/paradigmatic/Configrity)
- [Bee Config](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/)

(Disclaimer: I don't use these, so you will have to check that they support your types and format)

Comment: I'm new to Scala :-) and you were right I'm mixing java.util.List with scala.List. `import collection.JavaConversions._
val myList = modifyConfig.getStringList("mylist").toList` Did the trick. Thanks and I will check these links...

Answer (score 32):

For the record, since Scala 2.12 `JavaConversions` are deprecated so you can:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val myList: List[String] = modifyConfig.getStringList("mylist").asScala.toList
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library provides Java to Scala implicit list conversions via [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html):

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val myList: List[String] = conf.getStringList("mylist").asScala.toList
```

This replaces deprecated packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my scala wrapper https://github.com/andr83/scalaconfig - it supports reading native scala types directly from config object. In your case it will look:

```
val myList = modifyConfig.as[List[String]]("mylist")
```