# Trying to get a list with the Typesafe config library

Tags: scala, typesafe

I try to get a list from a config according to this example: [How to get a list with the Typesafe config library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913215/how-to-get-a-list-with-the-typesafe-config-library)

However, I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.properties @ file:/xxx/application.properties: configYYY has type STRING rather than LIST
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getList(SimpleConfig.java:252)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getHomogeneousUnwrappedList(SimpleConfig.java:323)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getStringList(SimpleConfig.java:381)
```

How can I get a list from typesafe? Below are my test code:

```
class Test extends FlatSpec {
  "Test" should "be about to get list" in {

    val configFactory = ConfigFactory.load();
    var disabledExtension = configFactory.getStringList("disabledExtension");
    assert(2==disabledExtension.size());
    assert(disabledExtension.get(0).equals("SH"));
    assert(disabledExtension.get(1).equals("ST"));
  }
}
```

And below my application.properties:

```
disabledExtension = ["SH", "ST"]
```

Comment: what's the config and wha't the code you are trying?

Comment: The error says that you don't have a list at this key, but a string. E.g. if you have something like `a, b` it should be `["a", "b"]` instead.

Comment: Yes I already using ["a", "b"] , but it still complaint this error, let me try something more simple first

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Comment: no, I turn out parse it myself, with disabledExtension = SH|ST

Answer (score 1):

application.properties has to be application.conf

Any property in "*.properties" file would be read as a string.