# Change Java List to Scala Seq?

Tags: scala

I have the following list from my configuration:

```
val markets = Configuration.getStringList("markets");
```

To create a sequence out of it I write this code:

```
JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(markets.iterator()).asScala.toSeq
```

**I wish I could do it in a less verbose way**, such as:

```
markets.toSeq
```

And then from that list I get the sequence. I will have more configuration in the near future; is there a solution that provides this kind of simplicity?

I want a sequence **regardless of the configuration library I am using**. I don't want to have the stated verbose solution with the `JavaConverters`.

Comment: which Configuration libarary is that?

Comment: com.typesafe.config, it is config-1.3.1.jar it helps me to get values from my configuration files

Comment: the question is already there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913215/how-to-get-a-list-with-the-typesafe-config-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list with the Typesafe config library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913215/how-to-get-a-list-with-the-typesafe-config-library)

Comment: Nop I want a Sequence out of it... I don't need a list, and I want as simple as defined by @Evgeny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html) is deprecated since Scala 2.12.0. Use [`JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html); you can import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` to make it less verbose:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val javaList = java.util.Arrays.asList("one", "two")
val scalaSeq = javaList.asScala.toSeq
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just import implicit conversions:

```
import java.util

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val jlist = new util.ArrayList[String]()
jlist.toSeq
```